# Calculating rectangle projected on the inside of a sphere

Tags: 3d, geometry, projection, spherical-coordinate

Imagine a projector at the centre of a sphere with radius r. I'm using a coordinate system where XY is the ground plane and +ve Z is 'up'. The projector has a pitch (+/-90 degree elevation from the XY plane), yaw (0-360 degree rotation about the Z axis), and a horizontal and vertical FOV (hFOV and vFOV). What I'm trying to calculate is the spherical rectangle of the projected image on the inside of the sphere (I'm presuming that it comprises four vertices connected by arcs). My aim is to draw the the projected rectangle in 3D, so I guess I'd also need to interpolate along each FOV to calculate the edge arcs that connect each vertex.

To make things a bit more fun, this (remarkable!) projector can have a hFOV up to 360 degrees and a vFOV of up to 180 degrees. Obviously a hFOV of 360 would no longer project a spherical rectangle, but I can treat this as a special case.

I tried treating the pitch/yaw/fov as polar coordinates, but the top and bottom of the projected rectangle get smaller as they get closer to the Z axis poles - intuitively, I'd expect the projected image to be the same size at any pitch/yaw provided it had the same FOVs.

Can anyone explain how I could calculate this? I considered calculating the hFOV positions in the XY plane then rotating them around an axis orthogonal to the projection's direction vector, but I can't help thinking there's an easier way.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the vFOV and hFOV expressed as angles (in degrees)?

Comment: @MarkLavin Yup, both FOVs are specified as angles in degrees.